# Highcharts data module and CSV: Displaying data points differently

Tags: highcharts

I am exploring Highcharts data module for the first time. I am loading a CSV file and this is working great for displaying the graph but I need to do an extra thing and I don't know if it's possible at this time:

Some of the data points need to be displayed differently than others. I need to use a different marker for these points, since the data can either be "real" or "approximative". Is there a way to identify these data points in the CSV and then having the data module assign a different point marker? The marker needs to be different for specific points of a series (not the whole series).

Here's a basic example on the cloud: https://cloud.highcharts.com/charts/ohucuv/1

Note however that I will not be using the cloud, and the CSV data will change over time, so the markers status will have to be taken from the CSV file. This way, only the CSV file will need to be updated and not the Highcharts/Javascript code. Is the seriesMapping object the way to go?.

Comment: Are the different markers dependent on the value of the point or some arbitrary assignment? You can add checks when you read the CSV into the `series.data` object to assign different markers if you know the parameters requiring a different marker.

Comment: It's based on the origin of the data. It could be an extra column in the CSV (ex: 0 = real data, 1 = approximative data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to hook into several highcharts options. First you need to use [`seriesMapping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.seriesMapping) to assign your column that contains estimate flag to a parameter in your series like below:

```
data: {
  csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
  firstRowAsNames: true,
  seriesMapping: [{
    // x: 0, // X values are pulled from column 0 by default
    // y: 1, // Y values are pulled from column 1 by default
    marker: 2 // Labels are pulled from column 2 and picked up in the dataLabels.format below
  }]
},
```

The name of `marker` is arbitrary - you can pick any you want. The next step is to use this flag. Since you already have your series based on the `csv` call you can then read your series on [`chart.events.load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load). In here you can iterate over your series elements and data points to get the value of `marker`. Once you have that value you can change the series marker symbol in the [`point.update`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) call. I am using the object notation here so that highcharts knows I am going to be modifying point object and not just x/y value:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      console.log(this.series);
      var theSeries = this.series;
      $.each(theSeries, function(i, series) {
        theData = series.data;
        $.each(theData, function(j, point) {
          console.log(point);
          if (point.marker == 1) {
            theSeries[i].data[j].update({
              marker: {
                symbol: 'triangle'
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
},
```

Here is a live [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lu2zkom/) showing this. I have set my estimate flagged points to use the triangle marker instead of the circle.

Edit to add multi-series approach.
Yes, you can do this with multiple series when using multiple columns. If you have a csv like:

```
x,somedata,somedata2,marker
1,2,10,0
2,3,11,0
3,5,12,0
4,6,13,0
5,7,14,0
6,7,15,1
7,8,16,1
8,9,17,1
9,10,18,1
10,11,19,1
```

You can still use the `seriesMapping` object. Notice that it looks like `[{}]`? You can add another series like:

```
data: {
  csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
  firstRowAsNames: true,
  seriesMapping: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 1,
    marker: 3
  },{
    x: 0,
    y: 2,
    marker: 3
  }]
},
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lu2zkom/2/). Basically for each series you define the columns that map to each element. Here the `x` is the same for both series (column 0) but the `y` values are from different columns (1 and 2). While we still use the same marker flag column for both (column 3).

The logic to apply the new marker still works because we are looping through each series in the chart (first example only had one series).

Comment: This looks very good. However I could I achieve this if I have more than one series? Your CSV is like this:

x,somedata,marker
1,2,0
2,3,0

but in my case, I will have multiple series and my CSV currently look like this:

date-category,series,data, marker
2005-05,Tokyo,10,0
2005-05,New-York,11,0
2005-09,Tokyo,18,1
2005-09,New-York,14,0

Comment: @TheJakester, updated answer. But, note that your example data set is a bit convoluted in that you have your series elements (Tokyo and NY) as row elements. To do this you may be better off parsing this data outside of highcharts' `data.csv` method.

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems to work perfectly. But since I have no way of knowing the number of series beforehands (and the column they are displayed in) I'll probably have no choice but to parse the data outside of the data module.

Comment: @TheJakester, yes that is a common issue. We roll our own data parser here so that we are not dependent on the `data` module. Ours are based on tables instead of CSV but the same problems/solutions apply.

Answer (score 0):

To change the markers:

1. Go to Simple
2. Click on Data series
3. Select your series
4. Go to Marker symbol, and select the marker for your serie

Do you have an advanced plan?

Comment: Thanks, however I will not be using the cloud, and the CSV data will change over time, so the markers will have to be taken from the CSV file so that only this file needs to change and not the Highcharts/Javascript code. Also, the marker needs to be different for specific points and not the whole series. I think maybe the seriesMapping object is the way to go.